# GPU utilization keeps around 70% if navigate to the page from webgl rendered page to a normal HTML page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, three.js, gpu

I have been working on a website where the homepage is built using three.js and it uses webgl for animation. Google Chrome task manager shows its GPU utilization of 50-70% on mac. On windows its around 10%.

The problem i am facing is if i navigation to another page using Ajax the GPU utilization remains up to 70% but it should drop down to near around 0%. Since when i refresh the same HTML page it shows it 0% GPU utilization.

The process that i follow during the Ajax is once i received the HTML and scripts of other page using Ajax i simply replace them in the current DOM. 
I have also tried `document.execCommand('Stop')` to stop the running scripts in the background. But still i am not getting any success.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Does it happen in all the browsers? What about memory usage? Does it drops or increases?

Comment: It was only happening on mac OS. It is now fixed. The webgl script was still running as it was loaded in the RAM. So i stop i using conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this come up on forums every once in a while, and I think that it has to do with WebGL, but I'm not entirely sure. Check to see if your GPU is working hard or if it's the CPU, or just memory usage. If it's GPU, i would wager that it's WebGL based.

If so, you might want to report this bug, as this is a pretty old one, and the developers of WebGL might appreciate more hardware reports to pinpoint it. But this seems to go back as far as 2011, and I'm not sure if it's ever been resolved.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=248002

https://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=921

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=637449

It seems that there is a history with WebGL and the browser not releasing memory after a tab is closed/refreshed. I would file a report with the browser you experienced this on.